# RMIServiceExporter not working, does not connect to RMI localhost at port 1099

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, rmi

I have exported Spring managed service beans into RMI service using following configuration:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">
        <property name="serviceName" value="spitterService"/>
        <property name="service" ref="spitterService"/>
        <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.spitter.service.SpitterService"/>
        <property name="registryHost" value="127.0.0.1"/>
        <property name="registryPort" value="1099"/>
 </bean>
```

but when i load my spring configuration file(deploy my application in Tomcat), it throws following exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spitter-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:872)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4681)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5184)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5179)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:601)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:198)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:184)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.list(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter.testRegistry(RmiServiceExporter.java:415)
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter.getRegistry(RmiServiceExporter.java:326)
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter.prepare(RmiServiceExporter.java:264)
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter.afterPropertiesSet(RmiServiceExporter.java:227)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1409)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:22)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:128)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:595)
    ... 30 more
```

please help me out..Thanks in advance

I also created an rmi client for consuming RMI service

```
public class SpitterMain {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String serviceURL = "rmi://localhost:1099/spitterService";
        try {
            SpitterService spitterService = (SpitterService) Naming.lookup(serviceURL);
            Spitter spitter = spitterService.getSpitter("panneerselvam");
            List<Spittle> spittles = spitterService.getSpittlesForSpitter(spitter.getId(), 25);

            System.out.println("Welcome>"+spitter.getName()+"( "+spitter.getUsername()+" )");

            System.out.println("Your Recent Spittles are:");

            for(Spittle spittle: spittles){
                System.out.println(spittle.getText()+" ON "+spittle.getWhen());
            }

        } catch (NotBoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SpitterMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SpitterMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SpitterMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Now i get following exception..

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiInvocationHandler (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:84)
    at com.spitter.client.SpitterMain.main(SpitterMain.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiInvocationHandler (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(LoaderHandler.java:535)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:628)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:294)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveProxyClass(MarshalInputStream.java:238)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1530)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1492)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1731)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    ... 3 more
```

Please check this guys...Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you remove the `registryHost` property it will dynamically create a host on 1099 since there isn't one already.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">
    <property name="serviceName" value="spitterService"/>
    <property name="service" ref="spitterService"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.spitter.service.SpitterService"/>
    <property name="registryPort" value="1099"/>
</bean>
```

Either that or start an [RmiRegistry](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/remoting/rmi/RmiRegistryFactoryBean.html) on 1099.

Comment: Great help From you @Gareth Davis, but can you tell me why i can't write "localhost" in registryHost property

Comment: basically because of this line of code https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/3.0.x/org.springframework.context/src/main/java/org/springframework/remoting/rmi/RmiServiceExporter.java#L325 if registryHost is specified then it assumes it isn't localhost (because that is the default) and since it is likely to be remote it can not hope to lazily create it

Answer (score 2):

You must create `myRmiExporter` and extend `RMIServiceExporter`
and then implement this method with this body

```
protected Registry getRegistry(String registryHost, int registryPort,
                                   RMIClientSocketFactory clientSocketFactory, RMIServerSocketFactory serverSocketFactory)
            throws RemoteException
    {

        if (registryHost != null)
        {
            // Host explictly specified: only lookup possible.
            if (logger.isInfoEnabled())
            {
                logger.info("Looking for RMI registry at port '" + registryPort + "' of host [" + registryHost + "]");
            }
            try
            {
                Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(registryHost, registryPort, clientSocketFactory);
                testRegistry(reg);
                return reg;
            }
            catch (RemoteException ex)
            {
                logger.debug("RMI registry access threw exception", ex);
                logger.warn("Could not detect RMI registry - creating new one");
                // Assume no registry found -> create new one.
                LocateRegistry.createRegistry(registryPort);
                Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(registryHost, registryPort, clientSocketFactory);
                testRegistry(reg);
                return reg;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            return getRegistry(registryPort, clientSocketFactory, serverSocketFactory);
        }
    }
```

it`s worked